# Linkedin Authorization Issue

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am able to get the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret from linkedin authorization API's.

But, I am not sure how this can be used to generate the "oauth2_access_token" parameter for calling any linkedin API.

Using header : "Authorization : Bearer {access_token}" doesn't work and gives error.

Answer (score 0):

The `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` can be leveraged in OAuth 1.0a flows towards LinkedIn e.g. you can now send a user of to the LinkedIn authorization endpoint using:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" . $oauth_token
```

If you want to leverage OAuth 2.0 you need to follow a different path that is describe here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 and you would not use `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`, but rather the Consumer Key and the Consumer Secret.

Comment: Ok. But if continue using Oauth 1.0, then how can I use the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret for calling any linkedin api. eg. fetching member profile.?